# Get results from MySQL statement and store in Python list and checking conditions

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a Python list "table_list" which has MySQL data tables names. I need to "start_time" field values from 1st data table and store in another list "file_sTimeList" after converting to datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

sq = """SELECT start_time FROM %s""" % (table_list[0])

cursor.execute(sq)
result = cursor.fetchall()
file_sTimeList = []
for row in result:
    file_sTime = f'{row[0]:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z}'
    file_sTimeList.append(file_sTime)

# print("file_sTime: ", file_sTimeList)
```

Then I get current server time - 24 hours time.

```
# get current server time
tz_PP = pytz.timezone('Asia/Phnom_Penh')
serverTime = datetime.now(tz_PP).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("serverTime: ", serverTime)



# get 24 hours  -  current server time
st_24hrs = datetime.now(tz_PP) - timedelta(hours=24)
serverTime_24hrs = st_24hrs.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print("serverTime_24hrs: ", serverTime_24hrs)
```

And finally I check each item from my previous list "file_sTimeList", if it exceeds 24hrs time and if so delete data.

```
# Clear DB all records , if exceed 24hrs
for st in file_sTimeList:
    if serverTime_24hrs > st:

        print("Exceed 24 hours")

        try:
            import datetime

            for r in range(len(table_list)):
                sql_1 = f"""DELETE FROM %s WHERE start_time = '{datetime.datetime.strptime(file_sTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}'""" \
                        % (table_list[r])
                cursor.execute(sql_1)
            print("DB clean")

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: ", e)
            raise e


    else:
        print("24 time")
```

However this doesn't give me correct output. What am I doing wrong here?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you are trying to compare a string with a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a `datetime` object for each element in the query instead of an f-string.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

sq = """SELECT start_time FROM %s""" % (table_list[0])

cursor.execute(sq)
result = cursor.fetchall()
file_sTimeList = []
for row in result:
    # Create a datetime instead of having a string
    file_sTime = datetime.strptime(f'{row[0]:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z}')
    file_sTimeList.append(file_sTime)
```

With that modification, it should work.